# Google Maps polygon/overlay - deleting

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlay

As a follow-on to a previous question... I am having no luck deleteing 
an overay that I have drawn on the map, so that I can start over.

My sequence:

1) draw the map
2) the user selects a city
3) I make an ajax call to get the boundary coordinates for 
   the selected city, and within the ajax success block, I 
   draw a boundary around that city - to be complete, I draw 
   a polygon on the map that completely covers the viewport, 
   except for a "hole" punch in it that exposes the city.

Great, so far

4) The user selects a new city
5) Same ajax call, but it starts with trying to wipe out the
   overlay by setting the "map" to null.

That doesn't work. The new city has a border around it, but
   the overlay has become darker, and the original "hole" is 
   still poked through.

I'm using:   negativeSpacePolygon.setMap( null );

to try and clear out the overlay. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_donut.html)

Comment: You wrote "What am I missing?". Enough information to let us answer the question.  Wild guess: negativeSpacePolygon is local to the function that creates it.

Answer (score 0):

See the "hide"/"show" buttons on this example from your last question:
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_complex_hole.html